# Can I see latest location of my stolen MacBook?

Tags: find-my-mac

My MacBook Air was stolen a couple of weeks ago. It had iCloud / Find my mac activated, so I activated stolen mode, and requested it to be deleted if it ever came online. This is exactly what happened today. Question is: Can I see where the MacBook was when it came back online? It does not show in the map in Find My iPhone, but obviously, it's not online anymore - it has been wiped. Is it possible to track the latest known location?